# How can 'the power of fear' be neutral?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The saturation of society by near- invisible secret agents, the
>   co- option of friends and family members – as has been notoriously documented in
>   Ethiopia of the Dergue, former East Germany, Idi Amin’s Uganda, among others, all
>   compelled to report on the tiniest nuances of discontent with, or indifference towards,
>   the state – these constitute part of the overt, structured forces of subjugations. To
>   apprehend fully the **neutrality** of the power of fear in recent times, indifferent to either
>   religious or ideological base, one need only compare the testimonies of Ethiopian
>   victims under the atheistic order of Mariam Mengistu with those that emerged from
>   the theocratic bastion of Iran under the purifi cation orgy of her religious leaders.

Which [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neutrality) applies? Fear is negative, so isn't 'the power of fear' necessarily so?

Source: p 181, [*Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA252#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Mark Shepherd

Comment: The text talks about the power of fear acting in a neutral way. Neutral as, not based on religion or ideology. If I hate people because they are black, my hate is not neutral. If I hate all people, my hate is neutral.

Comment: You need to read the entire sentence.  It's "indifferent to either religious or ideological base".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neutrality) Impartiality:
>
> [2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/neutrality) Absence of decided views, expression, or strong feeling:

Either of these definitions, or even a mix of the two, might be considered apt.

In this usage, the "power of fear" (not fear itself) is called neutral. This is because fear's power is no different even when seen in radically different areas of the world, both under oppression.

In the Ethiopian oppression example, the regime uses no belief in God in its propaganda. In the Iran oppression example, the regime is strongly tied to religion.

Despite these different approaches to oppression, the "power of fear" has no decided views, and plays no favorites. It subjugates the populace either way. Fear's power is equally negative in both examples.